# How do I lock a database so nothing can be modified

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to block all changes to a database for a period of time. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent any database write, then override [readonly?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/readonly?) method of `ActiveRecord::Base`

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def readonly?
    true
  end
end
```